# No module named 'numpy' Even When Installed

Tags: python, numpy, import, package

I'm using windows with Python 3.7.3, I installed NumPy via command prompt with "pip install NumPy", and it installed NumPy 1.16.4 perfectly. However, when I run "import numpy as np" in a program, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

I only have one version of python installed, and I don't know how I can fix this. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think `pip` refers to `python2.7`, check if you have something which looks like `pip3.7` and use it install numpy via `pip3.7 install numpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python3 is not supported under NumPy 1.16.4. Try to install a more recent version of NumPy:

`pip uninstall numpy`

`pip install numpy`